# "java.net.UnknownHostException" occurs while trying to call an public API

Tags: java, spring-boot

Am trying to make a simple request to an API. Am using Rest template to call that API.
I can able to access that API using PostMan. But while trying to call from JAVA am getting "**java.net.UnknownHostException**" issue.

Is that is because of proxy issue? If so how to add proxy in java code.
This is my simple code,

```
@GetMapping("/getallmakes") 
public ResponseEntity<String> getUser() { 
String url = USER_API; 
return restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
}
```

Also, suggest me how to make a API request without using proxy in JAVA.

Comment: If your system requires a proxy then there isn't a code workaround - it requires a proxy.  I'd ask your network admin about that.  If you do need to use a proxy there are plenty of examples available, depending on how you call the remote service.  It's unclear what `restTemplate` is in your code so it's impossible to answer without more detail.

Comment: Did you define proxy details in Postman or in PC proxy setting ? you can also define it in IDE

Comment: @GetMapping("/getallmakes")
 public ResponseEntity<String> getUser() {
  String url = USER_API;
  return restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);} this is what is about restTemplate in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill your proxy details in PROXY_SERVER_HOST and PROXY_SERVER_PORT

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_SERVER_HOST, PROXY_SERVER_PORT));
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
```

Use RequestFactory and define RestTemplate inc proxy details

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Use this customize RestTemplate

```
String response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

If you want to debug from local Machine via proxy

Goto File >> Setting >> Type in search bar "proxy" >> Click on HTTP proxy

Choose manual proxy configuration >> Fill in your proxy details

[image: Proxy settings]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. since am using public API am not aware of the PROXY_SERVER_HOST, PROXY_SERVER_PORT values. Can u suggest me how to get that.